# dpkg --configure -a fails on Ubuntu 16.04 after apt installation

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Every time i try to install something with apt-get i receive several errors. I think this is related to the output below. Unfortunately i can not remember, the package i tried to install before this errors.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a                          
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic (4.4.0-62.83) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-62-generic
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-62-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-62-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-62-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-62-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-62-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-62-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-62-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-62-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-62-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-firmware (1.157.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up console-setup (1.108ubuntu15.3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/console-setup.config:460: parse error near `}'
dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.62.65); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-firmware
 console-setup
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic
 linux-generic
 initramfs-tools
```

Thanks for your help!

Output of the first suggestion:

```
➜  ~ sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall plymouth console-setup
[sudo] password for jan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/107 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for console-setup:amd64
```

The second tip did not work, still the same problem.

Comment: Looks like the `plymouth` and `console-setup` packages may be corrupted. Could you please reinstall them (`sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall plymouth console-setup`)? If this command fails please [edit] your question to include its output. Thanks.

Comment: I removed by `apt-get remove --purge linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic` and installed `apt-get install linux-generic`.  That seemed to fix the problem.  Probably this is not necessary nor had any effect but I purged all `rc` status packages `dpkg -l | grep ^rc | awk '{print $2}' | xargs dpkg --purge`